# Replace value of a key based on first occurrence of value of another key

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

Suppose I have a list of dictionaries like the one below:

```
list=[{"name":'foo',"bleh":True},{"name":"foo","bleh":False},{"name":"panda", "bleh":True}]
```

For the first occurrence of the name 'foo', I want to copy its 'bleh' value to all future occurrences of 'foo'.

I was thinking of finding the index of the first occurrence in the list and somehow using it to make alterations within all the other dictionaries.

NOTE:
I don't want to hard code it for "foo", it should work for every unique value of the key "name" in each of the dictionaries in the list.

Comment: It doesn't have to be that complicated. Loop through the array and copy the value to all later elements with the same name. After you do this the first time for a particular name, the later copies will be redundant, but won't affect the result.

Comment: cerate dictionary to remeber values like `remember['foo'] = True` and iterate your list. For element check if name is in `remember` - if name is in `remember` then use value from `remember` as value in `bleh`. If name is not in `remember` then add it to `remember`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create dictionary to remeber values like `remember['foo'] = True` and iterate your list. 
For every element check if name is in `remember`. If name is not in remember then add it to `remember`. If name is in `remember` then use value from `remember` as value in `bleh`.

```
data = [
    {"name":'foo', "bleh":True},
    {"name":"foo", "bleh":False},
    {"name":"panda", "bleh": 'XXX'},
    {"name":"panda", "bleh":'Hello'},
    {"name":"panda", "bleh":'World'},
    {"name":"foo", "bleh":'other'},
]

remember = dict()

for item in data:
    if item['name'] not in remember:
        remember[item['name']] = item['bleh']
    else:
        item['bleh'] = remember[item['name']]

print(data)
```

It will use value from first `foo` to change `bleh` in all other `foo` and also it will use value from first `pandas` to change `bleh` in all other `pandas`.

Result:

```
[
    {'name': 'foo', 'bleh': True},
    {'name': 'foo', 'bleh': True},
    {'name': 'panda', 'bleh': 'XXX'},
    {'name': 'panda', 'bleh': 'XXX'},
    {'name': 'panda', 'bleh': 'XXX'},
    {'name': 'foo', 'bleh': True}
]
```